# A Paradox in graph theory?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, proof

I was reading minimum spanning trees in CLRS and came across the following corollary which is basis of algorithms to compute minimum spanning tree:

> **Corollary 23.2**
>
> Let G = (V,E) be a connected, undirected graph with a real-valued weight function w defined on E. Let A be a subset of E that is included in some minimum
>   spanning tree for G, and let C = (V_C,E_C) be a connected component (tree) in the forest G_A = (V,A). If (u,v) is a light edge connecting C to some other component in G_A, then (u,v) is safe for A.
>
> **Proof** The cut (V_C, V-V_C) respects A, and (u,v) is a light edge for this cut. Therefore, it is safe for A.

I find some inconsistency. Why? Let me show you:

### Some Statements skimmed from Corollary

These are the statements copied from the Same Corollary and its proof in the text:

STATEMENT 1 - G_A = (V, A)

STATEMENT 2 - (u,v) is a light edge connecting C to some other component in G_A.

STATEMENT 3 - The cut (V_C, V - V_C) respects A

STATEMENT 4 - (u,v) is a light edge for this cut.

### Lemma 1

Statement 1 and 2 imply (u,v) is in A

**Proof**

For purpose of contradiction lets assume that it does not belong to A. As (u,v) connects two components of graph **G_A** it must be an edge in graph G_A. As Set of edge is given by A in graph G_A it must belong to A which contradict our assumption.

### Inconsistency

Now Lemma 1 implies (u,v) belongs to A . Statement 3 implies the cut respects (u,v) which further implies (u,v) cannot cross the cut. Since it cannot cross the cut, it cannot be a light edge which contradicts Statement 4.

Does this imply the algorithms are incorrect. According to me G_A should be changed to G. Am I wrong?

## EDIT

### Other Possible Change

Well then Edge should belong to E as it cannot be any edge that is light. Let say we have edge set F superset of E that contains edge lighter than (u,v). Than upon finishing we will have MST not spanning G. An example has been attached to clarify the statement. Go to [Example](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_vNAD0pZJW5TU1CbEpobUw4cU0). Sorry for the shadowing. Stack Overflow wasnot uploading the image - I tried numerous times.

So shouldn't the last line of corollary be changed to (u,v) belongs to E and is a light edge for G_A for clarification purposes?

Comment: "As (u,v) connects two components of graph G_A it must be an edge in graph G_A." Why? If (u,v) was an edge in G_A, then it would belong to C since C is a connected component in G_A.

Comment: Not necessarily. Here's a simple example. Let G have vertices V={1,2,3,4} and edges E={(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,1),(1,3)}, so G

is a square plus one diagonal.

Now let A={(2,3),(4,1)}
, so these are the edges of G_A and hence G_A will have two components, each consisting of one edge of A. Let's pick C to be the component consisting of {2,3}, so the other component will be (4,1). (4,1) does not belong to C but it belongs to G_A

Comment: Exactly, and (u,v) in that case would be either (1,2) or (3,4), neither of them belonging to G_A or A.

Comment: @Abhishek Bansal But doesn't then it connects in Graph G and **Not in G_A**

Comment: Every vertex in original graph G is also a vertex in G_A (by definition). Hence any edge that connects C to any other vertex, that vertex shall be in G_A.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal See the Edit and let me know your views.